# Convert String to Type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, types

If I receive a string that contains the name of a class and I want to convert this string to a real type (the one in the string), how can I do this?

I tried

```
Type.GetType("System.Int32")
```

for example, it appears to work.

But when I try with my own object, it always returns null ...

I have no idea what will be in the string in advance so it's my only source for converting it to its real type.

```
Type.GetType("NameSpace.MyClasse");
```

Any idea?

Comment: Show us your sample failed code, also show us what is original type.

Comment: Also, tell us why/what you are trying to do.  There might be a work around would would not require you to send a string representation of the type.

Answer (score 474, accepted):

You can only use *just* the name of the type (with its namespace, of course) if the type is in `mscorlib` or the calling assembly. Otherwise, you've got to include the assembly name as well:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Namespace.MyClass, MyAssembly");
```

If the assembly is strongly named, you've got to include all that information too. See the documentation for [`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) for more information.

Alternatively, if you have a reference to the assembly already (e.g. through a well-known type) you can use [`Assembly.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx):

```
Assembly asm = typeof(SomeKnownType).Assembly;
Type type = asm.GetType(namespaceQualifiedTypeName);
```

Comment: It works fine... the only problem I have now is when I have a System.Collections.List or IList. How can I do that ? Because I don't only want the List Type but the type the list contains. Like List<string> by example. And remember thaht I don't know in advance what will be in the string, I just have to cast in a real Type. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Vinhent: At that point it's tricky - you need to parse out the generic part from the type arguments, and use `Type.MakeGenericType`. Do you have any control over the format of the input? Something like `List<string>` is a tricky name, because `string` is a C#-specific alias.

Comment: I saw one of your other post doing that : Type type = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"); it would be something like that I need. Because I receve the string and I must parse it in Type. Yes I have some control of the format of the string, but I cannot know if it will be a List, string, int, own solution objects in advance. It works well but not for List.

Comment: @Vinhent: Well if you can get the string to be of that sort of format, that's fine, and you can just use `Type.GetType`.

Comment: Will it works for a personal pbject from my own solution ? Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[myClasse, assemblyName]");  ? And what the `1 is use for ? And in case is an IList it says System.Collections.IList is not a GenericTypeDefinition. MakeGenericType may only be called on a type for which Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition is true.

Comment: @Vinhent: With the assembly name, it should work. The `1 indicates the number of type parameters.

Comment: Something like Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[namespace.myClass, AssemblyName]") always return null. It looks to work with System.String and System.Int32. And it doesn't work with an IList.

Comment: @Vinhent: Just experimenting, it looks like you need to double the square brackets for fully-qualified names: `Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[namespace.myClass, AssemblyName]]")` That should work with `IList<T>` as well.

Comment: Yes it works with [[]], cool! Didn't know those things, you helped me pretty good. For the IList, I was doing System.Collections.IList and didn't work but it works with System.Collections.Generic.IList

Comment: This is not one of my use case for now, but do you know if it would work with an array ? Something lie Type.GetType("System.String[]") ? Or "System.Array`1[[System.String]]" ?

Comment: @Vinhent: To debug all of these cases, choose something and print out its full name, e.g. `typeof(string[]).FullName`. If you learn how to do this yourself it'll be a lot easier than asking me for each variation.

Comment: I didn't notice the that the ','  between the type name and the assembly name is inside the quotes.  I was trying to pass two separate arguments and causing myself much frustration.   Worse, I think this is the second time (at least) that I've done this.

Comment: *"if the type is in `System.Private.CoreLib`"* in .NET Core

Answer (score 43):

Try:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(inputString); //target type
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // an instance of target type
YourType your = (YourType)o;
```

Jon Skeet is right as usually :)

**Update:** You can specify assembly containing target type in various ways, as Jon mentioned, or:

```
YourType your = (YourType)Activator.CreateInstance("AssemblyName", "NameSpace.MyClass");
```

Comment: The point is that Type.GetType is returning null for the OP. See my answer for the most likely cause.

Comment: It works fine... the only problem I have now is when I have a System.Collections.List or IList. How can I do that ? Because I don't only want the List Type but the type the list contains. Like List<string> by example. And remember thaht I don't know in advance what will be in the string, I just have to cast in a real Type. Is it possible ?

Comment: Might want to note that 'inputString' needs to be full namespace as thats what through me off in comparing yours to his.

Answer (score 19):

If you really want to get the type by name you may use the following:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).First(x => x.Name == "theassembly");
```

Note that you can improve the performance of this drastically the more information you have about the type you're trying to load.

Comment: It works fine... the only problem I have now is when I have a System.Collections.List or IList. How can I do that ? Because I don't only want the List Type but the type the list contains. Like List<string> by example. And remember thaht I don't know in advance what will be in the string, I just have to cast in a real Type. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4):

use following LoadType method to use [System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) to load all registered([GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)) and referenced assemblies and check for typeName

```
public Type[] LoadType(string typeName)
{
    return LoadType(typeName, true);
}

public Type[] LoadType(string typeName, bool referenced)
{
    return LoadType(typeName, referenced, true);
}

private Type[] LoadType(string typeName, bool referenced, bool gac)
{
    //check for problematic work
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(typeName) || !referenced && !gac)
        return new Type[] { };

    Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    List<string> assemblyFullnames = new List<string>();
    List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

    if (referenced)
    {            //Check refrenced assemblies
        foreach (AssemblyName assemblyName in currentAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        {
            //Load method resolve refrenced loaded assembly
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName.FullName);

            //Check if type is exists in assembly
            var type = assembly.GetType(typeName, false, true);

            if (type != null && !assemblyFullnames.Contains(assembly.FullName))
            {
                types.Add(type);
                assemblyFullnames.Add(assembly.FullName);
            }
        }
    }

    if (gac)
    {
        //GAC files
        string gacPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) + "\\assembly";
        var files = GetGlobalAssemblyCacheFiles(gacPath);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                //reflection only
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(file);

                //Check if type is exists in assembly
                var type = assembly.GetType(typeName, false, true);

                if (type != null && !assemblyFullnames.Contains(assembly.FullName))
                {
                    types.Add(type);
                    assemblyFullnames.Add(assembly.FullName);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //your custom handling
            }
        }
    }

    return types.ToArray();
}

public static string[] GetGlobalAssemblyCacheFiles(string path)
{
    List<string> files = new List<string>();

    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.dll"))
    {
        files.Add(fi.FullName);
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo diChild in di.GetDirectories())
    {
        var files2 = GetGlobalAssemblyCacheFiles(diChild.FullName);
        files.AddRange(files2);
    }

    return files.ToArray();
}
```