# cookie can have data other than string

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, message-passing

I have an object of a class **MeetingList** 
I want to pass this object through cookie it is giving me error while casting

**Writing Cookie**

```
HttpCookie cookies = new HttpCookie("QuickJumpCookie");
cookies["MeetingList"] = bal.GetMeetingList(personID, "Open").ToString();
Response.Cookies.Add(cookies);
```

**Reading Cookie**

```
HttpCookie cookies = Request.Cookies["QuickJumpCookie"];
MeetingList ml = (MeetingList) cookies["MeetingList"]; <-- Error in this line
```

Comment: `ToString()` means you are storing a string - you are not storing a `MeetingList`. When reading it, you can indeed not cast that `string` to a `MeetingList`. Serializing your object (and deserializing when reading it) should do the trick.(Just making it serializable is not enough of course, if you do not actually serialize it!)

Comment: All HTTP is strings. So no, cookies cannot be anything else but strings. However you can parse strings to ints, bools, objects etc... Just store it as JSON string and then parse it back from JSON string to Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you should serialize and then desirialize your MeetingList class

Serialize your object in cookie in some format(for example in JSON) and then  deserialize it. Personally i use this newtonsoft.com/json library. Your code will look like

```html
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourMeetingListObject)
```

and then

```html
MeetingList ml = (MeetingList) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cookies["MeetingList"])
```

Comment: use comments box for commenting if you need to

Comment: sorry, i have not enough reputation(at least 50) at the moment

Comment: It is giving a compile time error. Cannot convert type 'string' to 'MeetingList' Making the class Serializable does not solve as well

Comment: Try `cookies["MeetingList"].Value` instead.

Comment: instead of 'JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cookies["MeetingList"])' I used List<MeetingList> lml = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<MeetingList>>(cookies["MeetingList"]);  after inculding using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do is converting a string to an instance of a class. Unfortunately you can't do that. Please follow the link: [Convert String to Type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107536/convert-string-to-type-c-sharp)

You could use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class. More information: [Turn C# object into a JSON string in .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4)

Example:

```
HttpCookie cookies = new HttpCookie("QuickJumpCookie");
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(bal.GetMeetingList(personID, "Open"));
cookies["MeetingList"] = serializedResult;
Response.Cookies.Add(cookies);


HttpCookie cookies = Request.Cookies["QuickJumpCookie"];
MeetingList ml = serializer.Deserialize<MeetingList>(cookies["MeetingList"]);
```

Comment: I still cud not understand the solution. I was used to using Session. in session we do thing like this. I wud be pleased if write me the code or alter my code