# Entity Framework : Return a type from a string

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, variable-types

I'm using Entity Framework.
Let's suppose that in a string variable I have an object ( from an entity )  type's name, for example

```
dim tp as string="Myobj"
```

How can I get a type from this string ?
I try :

```
System.Type.Gettype(tp)
```

but this return always Nothing.

Thank you !

**Updated :** 
I try to use  the solutions in that link.
Now I'm using this instruction :

```
Dim t a type
Dim s  as string = "MyProg1.MyObj,MyProg1,Version=1.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null"
t=System.Type.GetType(s)
```

Bu the problem is that now the value of t is **MyProg.Myobj** , I'm expecting to return just **MyObj** as a type.

Comment: Is it related to VB.Net or Entity Framework?

Comment: 1. You need to include the full type name (e.g. Namespace.Type). 2. Case matters.

Comment: @Selva I have included the EntityFramework tag , because the object is from an entity.

Comment: @alex have you tried something like this, `tp.GetType()`?

Comment: sorry , but tp is a string. I don't want to get the type of tp.

Comment: tp is just a string that holds the name of one of  Entity framework classes.. Now I want to convert this string to a type.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with Entity-framework tag. because you are talking about converting types here and nothing about Entity-framework! Correct me if am wrong..

Comment: yes , but since the object is from an entity , I thought that the solution of the problem may be related with entity framework.

Comment: You should use the namespace of your project, not of the Entity Framework. As this 'entity' is located within your project. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107536/convert-string-to-type-c-sharp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName") returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)