# Returning type of a class based on its name in string format

Tags: c#, types

I have a codebase I'm working with that looks like the below

```
using namespace.scenario1;
...
using namespace.scenarion;

internal static Type GetType(string typeName)
{
  switch(typeName)
  {
    case "class1": return typeof(class1); // namespace.scenario1.class1
    ...
    case "classn": return typeof(classn);
  }
}
```

Every time I want to support a new class I have to add a using statement and a new case statement and it really feels like this can be automated away.

I tried an approach like the below but it sometimes returns null values

```
internal static Type GetType(string typeName)
{
   return Type.GetType(typeName);
}
```

I read a few posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107536/convert-string-to-type-in-c-sharp) that talk about having to set the assembly name but I'm still not not sure how to do this and would appreciate tips in the right direction. I know visual studio can figure out the assembly name since it can figure out that `class1` means `namespace.scenario1.class1`

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use directly the type name? I mean, if you do `Type.GetType("TheTypeName")` you will already achieve this without doing nothing...

Comment: Ok, sorry, didn't read the last part, if you want the real name of a type to use with GetType retrieve the full name with typeof(theType).AssemblyQualifiedName, it will return a fully qualified name including assembly and namespace.

Comment: @Gusman - when I try             

`return typeof(typeName).AssemblyQualifiedName;`

I get string is a variable but is used like a type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
internal static Type GetType(string typeName)
{
   return assembly.GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == typeName);     
   // Note: Exception occurs if it doesn't exist.       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Namespace.MyClass, MyAssembly");
```

Comment: Can you give a specific example that should pertain to the user's specific case as well?

Comment: Thanks Zdravko - I guess my question is also how to figure out the assembly name automatically. You can assume that each class belongs to its own namespace. If I have to put one assembly name for each case statement then I can keep things like they are right now.

Comment: Same comment for namespace (can't seem to edit my comment)