# Issue while getting the type of a class

Tags: c#

I am reading a app.config entry

```
  <add key="ClassNameSpace.ClassName" value="http://xxxx/xxx.asmx"/>
```

And I am trying to get the type for the key

```
  var section = configuration.GetSection(sectionKey.ToString());
  var appSettings = section as AppSettingsSection;
  if (appSettings == null) continue;

  foreach (var key in appSettings.Settings.AllKeys)
  {
      System.Type type = System.Type.GetType(typeof(key).AssemblyQualifiedName);
      var webService = new SecureWebService<type>().Service;
  }
```

But I am getting below error

'key' is a variable but is used like a type

Any idea to solve this issue

Comment: You can not call `typeof` with a variable, you need to call it with a Type (thats what the warning is trying to tell you) typeof(int) would be valid. You can call GetType with the key to get a type instance.

Comment: Nobody ever reads exception messages :( _"'key' is a variable but is used like a type"_ means that `key` is a variable, but you use it like a type in `typeof(key)`

Comment: what is the type of this "appSettings.Settings.AllKeys"

Comment: The type of that key is probably just "String". I think you want the value of that key to get the new type

Comment: So your question is how to get Type by class name?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107536/convert-string-to-type-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typeof() returns the Type of a type (class, interface, struct...) in the sense of the type name used in the code text.

For a string representation of a type, you should use:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(key); // full qualified like "namespace.type"
var webService = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // default constructor
```

Comment: That would not return what the OP wants, it would return the type of the key name container, not the type name the key represents. `Type.GetType(key.ToString())` is more likely to yield the desired result.

Comment: my guess is that OP wants to get `Type` by it's name. Like `"System.String"` -> `typeos(System.String)`, so just leave `System.Type.GetType(key)`

Comment: Indeed, key.GetType() returns "System.String". I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`GetType()` returns a `System.Type`object of an object.
`typeof()` returns a `System.Type` object of a datatype.

```
var section = configuration.GetSection(sectionKey.ToString());
var appSettings = section as AppSettingsSection;
if (appSettings == null) continue;

foreach (var key in appSettings.Settings.AllKeys)
{
    System.Type type = key.GetType();
    var webService = new SecureWebService<type>().Service;
}
```